# Have Exchange/Outlook process html tags in SMTP mail

Tags: smtp, exchange-2007, outlook-2010, html

I am working with a third party application that sends simple SMTP email messages.  The application doesn't respect line breaks or multiple spaces so the resulting email is barely legible.

Since the message comes through our SMTP server Outlook sees it as plain text.  Can I including html tags in the SMTP mail message and have Outlook process the tags to make the output more user friendly?

Comment: Have you considered changing the MIMEtype on your emails?

Comment: I tried that. I copied and pasted a simple example from another post:

`Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html <html> <body> This is a test. </body> </html>`

But Outlook just pulls it in as plain text.

Comment: If you change the MIME type to `text/html` and your email includes HTML then outlook will parse it properly. This is why MIME types exist.

Comment: Post the message with full headers (with, obviously, anything sensitive redacted). You've got something malformed if Outlook is "seeing" a MIME type of `text/html` as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP mail typically uses the [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) message format. This format is a very flexible system that allows a single message to contain several sections (called "parts"), each using it's own separate encoding and type.

Now, [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) mail is very old functionality and it actually predates the MIME format and so it will support message that are in that same format. typically, that is the way the most simple mail sending application will handle it: just as a bunch of text.

In practice, a MIME mail message is made of a set of headers followed by the message body. One of these headers indicates just how the message is encoded. If the message body is plain text, that header will read:

```
Content-type: text/plain
```

And if the message body is made of HTML it will usually be

```
Content-type: multipart/related
```

(or sometimes straight `text/html`)

Which tells the mail client that there is multiple parts in the message. At this stage, each part must indicate what type it is supposed to be in (in addition to several other parameters).

All that to say that, if you mail application sends the message as plain text and you want to convert that as HTML, you will have to, at the very least, change the message's content-type header in addition to change the message body itself.

Comment: I thought `multipart/related` was having both `text/plain` and `test/html` on the message. [From the RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.4) _In particular,
   each of the body parts is an "alternative" version of the same
   information._  . Having only `text/html` should be doing it.

Comment: ty @stephane.  If the mime type needs to be set in the header then it sounds like I can't hack around this by trying to set it in the body like I was trying to do.  I guess I need to see if there is a config file for this software that can be adjusted to change the mime type.

Comment: @user multipart/related means the message is made of multiple parts and it's usually what is used for HTML messages. You're right that you can change the header to be strictly text/html but that isn't really the  point I was trying to make. Still, I changed my answer to reflect that.